# Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed

Tags: flutter, gradle

I am receiving this error and could not solve it from past two days.[Here is the error, I am receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Zh7s.png)

I have tried almost every method on stack overflow but still no progress.
Could anyone please let me know that what can be a real issue behind this error?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue before with it beeing cause by the wrong java and or gradle version. Try downgrading to java 11 or using java 14 or newer and reinstall gradle.

Comment: I am using JAVA 17